# Laravel 4 Workbench not working in Pagodabox

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im developing a library hand in hand with a project I'm working on in L4 and I'm doing it in a Workbench as recommended. I have set the Service Providers etc and it works fine on my local machine. However when I pust to Pagodabox, the console gives me this:

```
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Coderollers\Formidable\FormidableServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123
```

Clearly, for some reason, on Pagodabox it is looking for my service provider in the vendors folder rather than the workbench folder. Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Try using artisans optimize and report your success (@CLI: `php artisan optimize`)

Answer (score 2):

For a workbench package to be loaded by Laravel it expects to find an `autoload.php` file within a `vendor` directory of your package. You'll need to run `composer install` from your workbench packages directory to install the package dependencies and have it dump an autoload file.

Once done Laravel will be able to detect and use your package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - actually I've read your guide on this on the web and that's how I created the workbench in the first place. However, it's working great locally - just when I git push to Pagodabox (with the autoload.php file not masked by gitignore) it seems to only check for its presence in the vendor directory and not in the workbench directory.